# How to replace this special character at all the places

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I tried the following the ways, but result could not be as per requirement( I mean getting same after running replace query). how to replace all the places that special character only?
Here is the Query.

```
select 
REPLACE(description,'‚'COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, N'&#x201A;') 
from Zstandars_25Feb2015 where Colname = 56
```

Result:
.

> ....the form  +  =  and  =  for cases in which ,  and
>    are all nonnegative ..........

Comment: What do you mean by result? Result of the query you have posted or the table contents after you run the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By keeping N, I am able to fetch the data..

select 
REPLACE(description,N'‚'COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN, N'‚') 
from Zstandars_25Feb2015 where Colname = 56

Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

whats the type of your description field? 
if its varchar, you shouldnt face any problem. I have run your query in my test table and i didnt get such a error, it might be something with your collation,  remove collate and try it again or change the collation to something else.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Removes special characters from a string value.
-- All characters except 0-9, a-z and A-Z are removed and
-- the remaining characters are returned.
-- Author: Christian d'Heureuse, www.source-code.biz
create function dbo.RemoveSpecialChars (@s varchar(256)) returns varchar(256)
   with schemabinding
begin
   if @s is null
      return null
   declare @s2 varchar(256)
   set @s2 = ''
   declare @l int
   set @l = len(@s)
   declare @p int
   set @p = 1
   while @p <= @l begin
      declare @c int
      set @c = ascii(substring(@s, @p, 1))
      if @c between 48 and 57 or @c between 65 and 90 or @c between 97 and 122
         set @s2 = @s2 + char(@c)
      set @p = @p + 1
      end
   if len(@s2) = 0
      return null
   return @s2
   end
```